# How to use values from a ConfigMap with key/value separated by equal symbol (=)?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, configmap

Given I have created a ConfigMap with a file like that :

```
VARIABLE1=foo
VARIABLE2=bar
```

Is there a way to access those values in Kubernetes or does it have to be in the YAML format?

Comment: your question makes no sense. I am surprised anyone actually tried giving an answer. Access the values in K8s or yaml format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say you have a file called `z` with the contents above. You have two options to make that into a ConfigMap.

### Option 1 (--from-file)

```
$ kubectl create cm cm1 --from-file=z
```

This will result in an object like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: cm1
data:
  z: |
    VARIABLE1=foo
    VARIABLE2=bar
```

There is no direct way to project a single value from this ConfigMap as it contains just one blob. However you can, from a shell used in `command` of a container source that blob (if you project it as a file) and then use the resulting environment variables.

### Option 2 (--from-env-file)

```
$ kubectl create cm cm2 --from-env-file=z
```

This will result in an object like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: cm2
data:
  VARIABLE1: foo
  VARIABLE2: bar
```

As you can see the different variables became separate key-value pairs in this case.

There are many more examples in the [reference documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/)